# Geary signature image

Tags: email, signature, geary

I found the signature option for Geary and I tried making a signature with an image. Referring to a file on my pc doens't work. When i paste the data-url from the image in the src box, it shows the image correct, but when I send the mail, the receiver gets the error 'filename of attachment not set' or equivalent depending on email client.
Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Kind regards

Comment: did you try html? <img src="url">

Comment: Yes, the complete signature is in html. An external URL does not work for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't any support including attached images in signatures, but there is an [open bug requesting this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754050) and it's something that we would like to add support for in the future.

I would be surprised if using a external URL or a data URLs for the image source (i.e. `<img src="https://..."/>`, or `<img src="data:..."/>`) don't work, however. If not, please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=geary) and we'll look into it.

(Edited to clarify the difference between *external* and *attached*)

Comment: An external URL does work, however users get a security alert and the pictures are blocked by default. The data URL does work and I see the images, however when they arrive the receiver gets the error no filename is set of the attachment. I'll file the bug, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I added `<img src="data:...."/>` in *~/.config/geary/account_01/geary.ini* .

In this file you can edit raw HTML, otherwise it will be escaped if you do it using geary UI.